# Selective comparison of class objects

Tags: python, comparison

I need to make multiple comparisons of class objects. However, only values of selected fields are subject to comparison, i.e.:

```
class Class:
    def __init__(self, value1, value2, value3, dummy_value):
        self.field1 = value1
        self.field2 = value2
        self.field3 = value3
        self.irrelevant_field = dummy_value

obj1 = Class(1, 2, 3, 'a')
obj2 = Class(1, 2, 3, 'b') #compare(obj1, obj2) = True
obj3 = Class(1, 2, 4, 'a') #compare(obj1, obj3) = False
```

Currently I do it this way:

```
def dumm_compare(obj1, obj2):
    if obj1.field1 != obj2.field1:
        return False
    if obj1.field2 != obj2.field2:
        return False
    if obj1.field3 != obj2.field3:
        return False
    return True
```

As my actual number of relevant fields is greater than 10, this approach leads to quite bulky code. That's why I tried something like this:

```
def cute_compare(obj1, obj2):
    for field in filter(lambda x: x.startswith('field'), dir(obj1)):
        if getattr(obj1, field) != getattr(obj2, field):
            return False
    return True
```

The code is compact; however, the performance suffers significantly:

```
import time

starttime = time.time()
for i in range(100000):
    dumm_compare(obj1, obj2)
print('Dumm compare runtime: {:.3f} s'.format(time.time() - starttime))

starttime = time.time()
for i in range(100000):
    cute_compare(obj1, obj2)
print('Cute compare runtime: {:.3f} s'.format(time.time() - start time))

#Dumm compare runtime: 0.046 s
#Cute compare runtime: 1.603 s
```

Is there a way to implement selective object comparison more efficiently?

**EDIT:** 
In fact I need several such functions (which compare objects by different, sometimes overlapping, sets of fields). That's why I do not want to overwrite built-in class methods.

Comment: Do you know in advance how many fields there are?

Comment: It would be quicker to be explicit about the fields that *should* be compared, e.g. with a class attribute `COMPARE_FIELDS = ['field1', 'field2', ...]`, then iterate over that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the fields exist for all instances in one particular comparison set, 
try saving the list to compare to the class.

```
def prepped_compare(obj1, obj2):
    li_field = getattr(obj1, "li_field", None)
    if li_field  is None:
        #grab the list from the compare object, but this assumes a 
        #fixed fieldlist per run.
        #mind you getattr(obj,non-existentfield) blows up anyway
        #so y'all making that assumption already
        li_field = [f for f in vars(obj1) if f.startswith('field')]
        obj1.__class__.li_field = li_field

    for field in li_field:
        if getattr(obj1, field) != getattr(obj2, field):
            return False
    return True
```

or pre-compute outside, better

```
def prepped_compare2(obj1, obj2, li_field):

    for field in li_field:
        if getattr(obj1, field) != getattr(obj2, field):
            return False
    return True    


starttime = time.time()
li_field = [f for f in vars(obj1) if f.startswith('field')]
for i in range(100000):
    prepped_compare2(obj1, obj2, li_field)
print('prepped2 compare runtime: {:.3f} s'.format(time.time() - starttime))
```

output:

```
Dumm compare runtime: 0.051 s
Cute compare runtime: 0.762 s
prepped compare runtime: 0.122 s
prepped2 compare runtime: 0.093 s
```

re. overriding *eq*, I am pretty sure you could have something like.

```
def mycomp01(self, obj2) #possibly with a saved field list01 on the class
def mycomp02(self, obj2) #possibly with a saved field list02 on the class

#let's do comp01.
Class.__eq__ = mycomp01
run comp01 tests
Class.__eq__ = mycomp02
run comp02 tests
```

Answer (score 1):

`dir()` not only includes instance attributes, but it'll traverse the class hierarchy as well. As such it does much more work than is needed here; `dir()` is really only suitable for debugging tasks.

Stick to using [`vars()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#vars) instead, perhaps combined with [`any()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all):

```
def faster_compare(obj1, obj2):
    obj2_vars = vars(obj2)
    return all(value == obj2_vars[field]
               for field, value in vars(obj1).items() if field.startswith('field'))
```

`vars()` returns a dictionary containing the attributes of the instance only; in the above generator expression I access both the attribute name and its value in one step by using the `dict.items()` method.

I replaced the `getattr()` method call for `obj2` to use the same dictionary approach, this saves a framestack push and pop each time as the key lookup can be handled in bytecode (C code) entirely. Note that this does assume you are not using properties; only actual instance attributes are going to be listed.

This method still has to do more work than hardcoding the `if` branches, but it is at least not performing all that bad:

```
>>> from timeit import timeit
>>> timeit('compare(obj1, obj2)', 'from __main__ import obj1, obj2, dumm_compare as compare')
0.349234500026796
>>> timeit('compare(obj1, obj2)', 'from __main__ import obj1, obj2, cute_compare as compare')
16.48695448896615
>>> timeit('compare(obj1, obj2)', 'from __main__ import obj1, obj2, faster_compare as compare')
1.9555692840367556
```

Comment: shouldn't that be `return not any(value != obj2_vars[field]...` ?

Comment: @overactor: oops, inversion trip-up there. No, it should be using `all()` instead.